# Have a job interview, might need to take two weeks off shortly after being hired. Should I mention it?

Tags: interviewing, new-job

I've been unable to find a job for a long time. I just got a call back for a retail position. It's not the greatest, but at least it's income.

The problem is that my grandfather recently died and was a bit of a hoarder. I applied to this job about a month and a half ago, and hadn't heard back. So I offered to fly out to my grandfather's and clean out the house and get everything in order for it to be sold. I fly out in the middle of August and return two weeks later. Flight's are non-refundable and not Southwest so I can't just change them.

I would imagine that if I got the job it would start mid July or early August. How should I disclose this information? Should I tell them during the interview?

Comment: if the interview goes well.  IF and WHEN they ask "when can you start?" just say this:  *I can start anytime, one thing, unfortunately my grandfather passed, and I may have to fly to XYZ for one week to assist. Other than tha I can start anytime.*  Otherwise, say nothing.

Answer (score 12):

> Should I tell them during the interview?

Yes. Usually employers ask for your availability: "when can you start?" When they ask about that, that's when you tell them your availability.

No reasonable employer would expect you to cancel important plans that you made before you had even committed to a start date, but they'd want to know something like this before deciding to hire you. They might approve the two week break or they might ask you to start after you get back. Or maybe they need to fill the position quickly and they can't afford either of those options.

No matter the case, they'll appreciate knowing ahead of time what your availability is. The worst case scenario is you don't tell them until after you start, and they fire you.